# Foreign key form field in django admin

Tags: django, popup, foreign-keys, admin

I want to adjust my app based on django admin to be more userfriendly.

[Add offer page](http://www.picvalley.net/v.php?p=u/2235/44029312618348224641322224549l8GQmQMnkHXjlvm2LJTN.PNG)

The following admin page is good when the user creates an Offer to the client, which is already registered in the system. But if the customer is a new one, then user has to click on a + and submit the 'Add new client' form in the popup. This is so confusing.

How can I change this behaviour to fill in the client data on the same page with inline but not in the popup?

Here is my admin.py.

```
class OptionOffer(admin.ModelAdmin):
   fieldsets = (('', {'fields': (('client'), 'startDate', 'regNumber')}),)

class OptionClient(admin.ModelAdmin):
   fieldsets = (('', {'fields': ('code')}),)
```

and the model.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Code"), max_length=11)

class Offer(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, verbose_name = _("Client"))
    startDate = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = _("Start date"))
    regNumber = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Registration number"), max_length=6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some Javascript framework like jQuery and load the popup in the edit page using an iframe or something similar. Or use some lightbox style popup instead of the Django standard one.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get a better solution without doing some serious hacking of the django admin. You might come across (or be pointed to) [InlineModelFormsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects), which provide a form at the bottom of your current form allowing you to add clients inline. While this might seem like what you need, you will soon see that it doesn't fit your use-case, as it requires a foreign key relationship from the Client to the Offer as opposed to what you have which is a ForeignKey relationship from the Offer to the Client

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this mean that any step left or right away from conventional django admin app will make me suffer? It is a very common case that user want to do logically related changes on a single page. Perhaps I might not use Django at all for this kind of problem. What do you think?  Can you point me to a nice open source example of django admins usage, so I could learn from best practices.